# Computing the power series of $\sqrt{1-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, power-series

I am trying to manually present the function $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x}\ \ $(for $0 \le x \lt 1$) as a power series and to prove that the power series converges to the function value $f(x)$.

I am using Maclaurin's power series formula.

For the n-th derivative ($n \ge 2$) I got this

$$f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-1).1.3.5 \dots (2n-3)}{2^n} . (1-x)^{-(2n-1)/2}$$

I hope it's correct. Is it?

Then using that I was able to compute the power series and to prove that it converges.

But in order to prove that it converges to the function value $f(x)$, I think I need to prove that the remainder term converges to zero as $n \to \infty$

So I have these questions. Is my remainder term (which I computed by hand) correct?

$$R_n = \frac{(-1)1.3.5 \dots (2n-1)}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!} . \frac{x^{n+1}}{(1-\theta x)^{(2n+1)/2}}$$

Here we just know that $\theta$ is some number, $\theta \in (0,1)$ and $\theta$ depends on $x$.

And then how do I prove that $R_n$ goes to zero as $n \to \infty$ ?

Comment: Peano remainder or Lagrange remainder?

Comment: I am not too good with the terminology but yes, I think it's the Lagrange form of the remainder.

Comment: You can try to compute the limit of $\frac{R_{n+1}}{R_n}$.

Comment: @Lelouch How? The two thetas will be different, no? And what will that give me? Btw, are my computations correct (otherwise I would just waste my time to go further)?

Comment: As you dont show your computations its not possible to check a possible mistakes (and I dont know by heart the remainder, you can probably find it on internet...). If the absolute value of the limit is $<1$ then the sequence will converges to $0$.

Comment: @Lelouch Will the two thetas in $R_n$ and $R_{n+1}$ be the same or different? I think different, right?

Comment: You can try with the theta giving the worst error i.e $\theta=0$ I guess. I didn't investigate more.

Comment: I get $$\lim R_n = \lim C\cdot \frac{n^n}{n^{5/2}(n+1)^n}\left(\frac{x}{1-\theta x}\right)^n$$, and we cannot guarantee it is convergent to $0$. Is your remainder computed correctly?

Comment: @MathFail Hm, I am more confused now. WA says it's convergent even for all $|x| \le 1$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=power+series++sqrt%281-x%29 I just cannot prove the remainder term goes to zero. But it should since WA says this, right?

Comment: @MathFail Well, my remainder is just $\frac{f^{n+1}(\theta . x) . x^{n+1} } {(n+1)!}$ This is the general form of the remainder in the Maclaurin formula. And since computing the n-th derivative is easy, I think my remainder is correct. But that was part of my question: is my remainder correct, could someone confirm that? And if it is, how do we prove it goes to zero for any $x \in [0,1)$?

Comment: You have to use Cauchy’s form of the remainder theorem

Comment: Here's a similar question and it was also remained unanswered. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820022/prove-sqrt1x-can-be-represented-by-a-power-series?rq=1

Comment: @Eric Oh... So I need to do something like this maybe https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Real_Analysis_(Boman_and_Rogers)/05%3A_Convergence_of_the_Taylor_Series-_A_%E2%80%9CTayl%E2%80%9D_of_Three_Remainders/5.03%3A_Cauchy%E2%80%99s_Form_of_the_Remainder There's an example here with $\sqrt{1+x}$ for $x \in (-1,0)$ I think my problem is kind of equivalent (very similar) to this example here. Right?

Comment: Exactly. That’s the right idea.

Comment: The term $ 2n-3$ in your tormula for $f^{(n)(x)}$ is incorrect. It should be $2n-1$.

Comment: The generalized binomial theorem is due to Isaac Newton, not to Maclaurin.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sqrt~$ is analytic on $\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0],$ you get for free that [the limit of the Taylor series of $f$ (on its disc of convergence) is $f.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/551880/386889) You don't have to bother about $R_n.$ Just compute the coefficients of the [Taylor series of $f$:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/732660/386889)
$$\sqrt{1-x}=1-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac2{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\left(\frac x4\right)^{k+1}$$
and derive [its radius of convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2716624/386889), which is equal to $1.$

Comment: OK, if you ignore the specification "manually".  I take that to mean that the OP is not supposed to used a big theorem to do this.